# Clear PHP Cookies array

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I know how to set PHP cookies in an array but can I clear it without a loop?
For example I'm setting these four cookies

```
// set the cookies
setcookie("cookie[four]", "cookiefour");
setcookie("cookie[three]", "cookiethree");
setcookie("cookie[two]", "cookietwo");
setcookie("cookie[one]", "cookieone");

// after the page reloads, print them out
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
    foreach ($_COOKIE['cookie'] as $name => $value) {
       $name = htmlspecialchars($name);
       $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
       echo "$name : $value <br />\n";
    }
}
```

> **OUTPUT:**
>   four : cookiefour 
>   three : cookiethree 
>   two : cookietwo 
>   one : cookieone

To clear the cookies, i use the following loop

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
    foreach ($_COOKIE['cookie'] as $name => $value) {
        setcookie ("cookie[".$name."]", "", time() - 1);
    }
}
```

Are there any way I could clear the cookies without a loop? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you pretty much need to loop through existing cookies as the way to delete/expire a cookie, as you have in your code via setcookie, is one cookie at a time.

Comment: I thought there were functions like ClearAllCookies(); in PHP haha

Answer (score 1):

Could try

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
    setcookie ("cookie", array());
}
```

or even

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
    setcookie ("cookie", array('one'=>'','two'=>'','three'=>'','four'=>'',));
}
```

if you need the indexes

Comment: Warning: setcookie() expects parameter 2 to be string

Comment: Checked doc on php.net and it looks like @JBzd is correct. you must remove each element of the cookie array individually.